# How to download files without using Download Manager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have developed an mp3 downloader which downloads mp3 from a URL to android phone using DownloadManager. But the problem is that if you uninstall the app, the files previously downloaded will get removed from the folder. I would like to get alternate methods or libraries to download mp3 files (only mp3) from a URL to android device.

```
storage = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC;

request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
                                extension =".mp3";
                                request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
                                request.setTitle(vMeta.getTitle());
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(storage, vMeta.getTitle() + extension);
                                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                manager.enqueue(request);
```

vMeta.getTitle() - returns the title of the mp3 file and ext contains ".mp3" .

The file is getting downloaded and it is working fine.

NOTE : I have also tried `DownloadManager.Request`

Comment: Can I use it like this ? setDestinationUri(storage, vMeta.getTitle() + extension);

Comment: request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"put whatever you want");

Comment: setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(storage + vMeta.getTitle() + extension)) ;

Comment: `storage + vMeta.getTitle() + extension` ??? Nobody knows what path that would be. It makes no sense to post such code.

Comment: Try **AsyncTask** as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/7756492).

Comment: @MikeM. I tried this :                                     ` request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, vMeta.getTitle() + extension))); ` 

and I got this error : 

                  java.lang.SecurityException: Destination must be on external storage: file:///Music/Pt%20.Kumar%20Bose%20and%20anindo%20chattergee%20in%20green%20room%20practice%20-1.mp3

Comment: @MikeM. Yes it is still happening. Confirmed in different mobile phones running Android 6.0

Comment: Confirmed. It also happens with my suggested method, too. That's unexpected.

Comment: Aha! Found a pretty simple workaround, though. If you rename the file after it's downloaded, it doesn't get deleted upon uninstallation. You could download it to a temp name, and just rename it when it's done.

Comment: Yep, even works in the public storage directories. So you could, for example, download it with a .tmp extension, then rename it with an .mp3 extension after the download.

Comment: @MikeM. Could you post the code as the answer?

Comment: Sure. Gimme a little bit to put something together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167014/discussion-between-psn-and-mike-m).